# Duplicated React/Redux project resulting "async_hooks" not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

First of all, thank you all for your attention. I'm new about react/redux code, and I have an old project that already existed and I only need to duplicate it because they need the same version with some different parameters.

So, I duplicated the old project, created a new gitlab project for it, changed what I needed(practically only text) on the duplicated project, then how it was showing many errors after "npm run build", I did:

0. Inside the package.json file I changed "node-sass" to use the version 4.11.0 because the old one was generating some "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module" kind of errors(as I said, this was a duplication from a old project that even is still running on production has many deprecated dependencies).
1. I deleted the package-lock.json file.
2. I deleted also the node_modules folder.
3. I did "npm install" already on the master branch of the folder to create again the node_modules.

As you can see, I just tried to delete the package-lock.json file then I deleted the node_modules folder, and finally I did "npm install", but when I tried "npm run build", the async_hooks error showed up... I'm stuck in this part.

After these basic steps, the error happened: Cannot resolve module 'async_hooks'. I tried to "npm install async_hooks" but it didn't work, I also tried to put the "async-hooks" on the package.json file but it didn't work, and finally I also tried put a new version from bluebird there but didn't work too.

**How to install this "async_hooks"? Because even after doing "npm install async_hooks" it didn't work yet.** I run "npm run build" but the same error happened.

See below the full result:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'async_hooks' in C:\xampp\htdocs\careers\node_modules\bluebird\js\release
 @ ./~/bluebird/js/release/util.js 410:18-40

ERROR in ./~/bluebird/js/release/promise.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'async_hooks' in C:\xampp\htdocs\careers\node_modules\bluebird\js\release
 @ ./~/bluebird/js/release/promise.js 34:4-26
```

. Here is my package.json file:

```
"main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "build": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
"license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^v8.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.1.0-beta.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chai": "~3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "~2.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "~2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "~8.1.0",
    "mocha": "~2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~0.14.7",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "~1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "~0.13.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "griddle-react": "~0.6.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "nested-property": "^0.0.7",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-datetime": "^2.10.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-ga": "^2.3.5",
    "react-redux": "~4.3.0",
    "react-router": "~2.0.1",
    "redux": "~3.1.7",
    "redux-form": "^6.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

. and here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'./js/'),
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Any ideas?